# How to use nl2br with php session variables

Tags: php, variables, session, session-variables, nl2br

I am trying to create line breaks in my php script. I have variables using session, and I cannot figure out how to create line breaks with them. I have tried the following (as well as different combinations) as well as googling to try and find a solution with absolutely no luck at all.

```
 <?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];

echo nl2br("First Name : $_SESSION['firstname']\n\r");
echo nl2br("Last Name : $_SESSION['lastname']\n\r");
?>
```

I am grabbing variables from a form on a previous page. If I just echo the variables like so,

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];

echo $_SESSION['firstname'];
echo $_SESSION['lastname'];
?>
```

It works just fine. I am having a difficult time trying to find out how to use the syntax of nl2br (which I have also successfully used before) with session variables in php.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### -Anthony

UPDATE: Answer below via Marc B. When session variables are in double-quotes, single-quotes must be removed.

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];

echo nl2br("First Name : $_SESSION[firstname]\n\r");
echo nl2br("Last Name : $_SESSION[lastname]\n\r");
?>
```

Comment: Look at the section on `unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` [this reference question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/13935532#13935532) for suggestions on how to quote it correctly. Your problem isn't specific to `nl2br()`, but just with the general behavior of double-quoted strings with complex variables.

Comment: Also, linebreaks as a combination of carriage-return, newline are `\r\n`, not `\n\r` as you have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nl2br` is a glorified remake of `str_replace("\n", "<br />", $text)`. If your string doesn't have **ANY** newline characters, there's nothing to replace and you've basically got an expensive `print`/`echo` occuring.

You also have PHP syntax errors. You cannot use quoted array keys in a double-quoted string:

```
echo "$array[key]"; // ok
echo "$array['key']"; // wrong
echo "{$array['key']}"; // ok - extended syntax.
```

Comment: nl2br is a **little** bit more fancy than that: it does not replace, but adds <br>, and it detects more than \n linebreaks

Answer (score 0):

```
echo nl2br("First Name" . $_SESSION['firstname'] . "\r\n");
echo nl2br("First Name" . $_SESSION['lastname'] . "\r\n");
```

Or could you try?

```
echo "First Name".$_SESSION['firstname']."<br />";
echo "Last Name".$_SESSION['lastname']."<br />";
```